# How to get GridLookup with complex name

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, gridview, devexpress

I'm trying to get GridLookup selected value,

```
@Html.DevExpress().GridLookup(settingsGrid =>
{
    settingsGrid.Name = "CommandeDetailEnCours.Compte";
    settingsGrid.KeyFieldName = "Numero";

    [...]
}).BindList(Model.ListeComptes).Bind(Model.CommandeDetailEnCours.Compte).GetHtml()
```

The question is: How I can get Value because in javascript

```
"CommandeDetailEnCours.Compte".GetGridView() [...]
```

not work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the client-side GetValue method in the following manner.

To retrieve the complex name on the client use the [How to use the ClientInstanceName and Name properties when they contain special characters](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/ka18687/) approach.

```
var lookupClientInstance = ASPxClientControl.GetControlCollection().GetByName("CommandeDetailEnCours.Compte");
var value = lookupClientInstance.GetValue();
alert(value);
```